# I am unable to eat tomatoes. What can I use instead, especially in soups?

Tags: substitutions, tomatoes

My digestion doesn't like tomatoes, and all the soup recipes I like call for them.  Is there anything I could substitute?

Comment: Just find a recipe for soup that doesn't use them. French onion, chicken, pea & ham, leek & potato etc.

Comment: Are these soups with chunks of tomato, or with tomatoes blended into the base?

Comment: Tomatoes are basically squishy sweet & sour things.  You might be able to get away with cooking chunks of carrots 'til they're soft (but not dissolved), and a splash of vinegar.  Actually, cooking the carrots w/ the vinegar already in there might be good so they don't break down completely (but it'll also affect how other things soften)

Comment: @Joe Interestingly, that's the theory behind the product in Cindy's answer.

Comment: Sauces based on red bell pepper (piperade) can stand in for tomato sauces in some projects...

Comment: Tomatillos https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomatillo thicken down nicely. Used as basis for green chili. Unfortunately they're in the same family as tomatoes and peppers, *Solanaceae*, so maybe a bit of caution. They used to be hard to find, but not so much anymore in the states.

Answer (score 6):

There is an alternate product available that does not contain tomatoes. It is called  [Nomato](http://www.nomato.com/products.htm) .

It is described on the home page as:

> Nomato sauces are a delicious natural alternative to traditional tomato based products.

Additional info:

> Nomato may be substituted in any recipe using tomato sauce, barbecue sauce, ketchup or salsa.
>
> Nomato is made from vegetables and seasonings. It contains no soy, dairy, wheat, gluten, nuts and of course no tomatoes!

I am not promoting this product and, quite frankly, have not tried it. However, I did read several great reviews about it.

Comment: The lesson to be learned from looking at that product's ingredient list: Use a carrot puree and additional seasonings.

Answer (score 2):

Sour plums have a really similar texture and flavor to tomatoes - they are a base in a lot of Middle Eastern soups

Answer (score 2):

For visual appeal sometimes you do just need the red of the tomato.  I am unable to enjoy them either...so I *substitute red peppers* cut in 1/4" strips, as long or as short as I want them.

Answer (score 2):

I tried using beets to make a soup that called for tomatoes and I'm quite happy with the results. I diced raw beets very fine and sautéed them in with the onion, adding carrots and celery a few minutes later, since beets take longer to cook.

I used paprika and a little turmeric to make the colour look closer to that of tomatoes. I also used about a teaspoon of cider vinegar to replicate the acidity of tomatoes. (You might roast the beets and blend them up with some broth if you want a smoother consistency like tomato sauce.)

Answer (score 2):

Carrots, tamarind, bilimbu, olives, unripe mangoes, beets, vinegar, basil, oregano just depends on what you need tomato Flavor for. These substitutions are good for some replacements but not others.

Answer (score 2):

My stomach doesnt love tomato at all.
Since a few years I only eat white pizza when ordering.

For other dishes that uses a tomato paste you can replace it with a pumpkin paste.
Lasagna with pumpkin and sausage meat is a very nice combination.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Many home-made soups use a tomato base. After unsuccessfully  trying every substitute I could find for tomatoes, I finally discovered that pear juice makes a great substitute base in soups. Buy just juice. If you are using pear juice packed with pears, you'll have to remove the pears. I haven't tried to puree them, but suspect that might work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a little experimentation!

Tomatoes have a delicious blend of savory (umami) and acid. Use varying proportions of ingredients that are acidifying or are high in glutamates!

Vinegars and various citrus juices are a natural source of acid, as are yogurts and wines or beer (yum!).

Sources of glutamates can include aged cheese (like Parmesan or Asiago), anchovies/anchovy paste, soy sauces, miso paste, fish sauce, and Worcestershire (also containing fish).

You’ll likely go through a few iterations of each recipe until you find a balance that you like, but I bet you can get a pretty satisfying flavor profile out of it if your willing to tinker a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Better than substituting is making a soup that doesn't use tomato in the first place. Examples include:

- Leek and potato
- Pea and ham
- French onion
- Cream of (chicken, mushroom, etc.)
- The runnier kinds of dhal

If you look carefully, you'll find vegetable soup recipes without tomato as well, or in which tomato is such a small component you can simply omit it.

Comment: I noticed that my comment from years ago should have been an answer - and had more votes than any actual answer! So while the question was bumped anyway seemed like a good time to fix that

Answer (score -2):

If you can’t eat tomatoes, stay away from all nightshades including peppers and potatoes. Your digestion will thank you. I use nomato sauce and don’t give up if the first version doesn’t turn out perfectly, when done right it’s almost a perfect match.